# Sliding div (for each row) is not functioning properly in a table

Tags: javascript, php

In my table I'm echoing the following sliding div in each row. The problem is the sliding div is toggled for every row when you click "Report". I'm thinking the way to resolve this is using the unique id I have for each row in the variable $row['reportid']. Any help would be appreciated.

PHP:

```
echo '
<form action="foobar.php?foobar=' . $row['reportid'] . '" method="post" id="foobar">
<A NAME="#peer' . $row['reportid'] . '"> (<a href="#peer' . $row['reportid'] . '" class="show_hide2">Report</a>)
<div class="slidingDiv2">
// Content inside sliding div has been omitted
// I removed all the form content too.
 </div>
</form>
';
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".slidingDiv2").hide();
    $(".show_hide2").show();

    $('.show_hide2').click(function(){
        $(".slidingDiv2").slideToggle();
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: What is this `<A NAME="#peer' . $row['reportid'] . '"> (<a href="#peer' . $row['reportid'] . '" class="show_hide2">Report</a>)` ? Why there is an inner `a` in brackets inside the outer one? And the outer `a` doesn't have a closing tag? And both have the same id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `$(".slidingDiv2").slideToggle();` with `$(this).next().slideToggle();` so you would toggle the panel relevant to the `a` clicked, which would be the next element after the `a`:

```
$('.show_hide2').click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle()
});
```

Also do you really need to do this ?:

```
$(".slidingDiv2").hide();
$(".show_hide2").show();
```

You can add a css rule for `slidingDiv2` class to your css file:

```
.slidingDiv2 {
    display: none;
}
```

and I believe class `show_hide2` will be visible by default.